# Can't make form 'close itself'?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I have one form that opens another form upon clicking a button. When the new form opens, I have a progress bar complete via a loop, then I want the form to close. Here is the button click event that launches the new form.

```
    private void calculateButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (checkFormComplete())
        {
            ProgressForm proForm = new ProgressForm();
            proForm.Show();
        }

    }
```

And here is the code for the new form that completes a progress bar that should then close itself.

```
    public ProgressForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        for (int i = 0; i < 101; i++)
            calculationProgress.Value = i;

        this.Close();
    }
```

However, upon running this I get:

> Cannot access a disposed object. Object name: 'ProgressForm'.

And the debugger points to this line of my main form:

```
proForm.Show();
```

**I'm not sure I understand why, or what the proper way to do this is. How is that line being called after the close statement inside my new form?**

Comment: It looks a lot like you are calling Close() from the ProgressForm constructor, so calling Show() [from calculateButton_Click] after you called Close (which will call Dispose) won't work

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The form is trying to close itself before it's even shown (because you have your code in the constructor). Put your progress bar code and `Close()` call in the `FormLoad` or `FormShown` event instead. Example:

```
private void ProgressForm_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 101; i++)
    {
        calculationProgress.Value = i;
        Application.DoEvents(); // force the form to update itself
    }

    this.Close();
}
```

Comment: If you use *Application.DoEvents*, bue *sure* you know how it works http://stackoverflow.com/a/5183623/141172.  They generally **don't** behave as you would want.

Comment: Hmmm... but then the changes to *calculationProgress* will not show because the WM_PAINT events are notprocessed.

Comment: Lol chances are he's not going to see anything anyway with a loop that is only incrementing a value. Anyway - added it back in, thanks for the link to the other question.

Answer (score 2):

Allow the loading to complete before you try to close the form :-)

You should start your progress bar loop in the Form_Load event.

However note that looping like that will cause your form to *lock up* until the progress bar completes rendering.

Do the progress loop in a background thread.  A [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) is ideal for running the progress loop.

```
public proForm()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    backgroundWorker1.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
    backgroundWorker1.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
}

proForm_Load()
{
    backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
}

private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{

    (int i = 0; i < 101; i++) worker.ReportProgress(i);
}

private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
        resultLabel.Text = (e.ProgressPercentage.ToString() + "%");
}

private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    this.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A constructor is used to **initialize** an object not destroying the object in the contructor itself.

So a constructor should contain intialization code.

Your code is trying destroy the object with the `this.Close();` in the constructor hence the error.

Put your code in `Load` event of Form.

Change the `calculationProgress.Value` through a **BackgroundWorker's** `ProgressChanged` event